# concatenation of an array ends in a limitless empty arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array with 9 elements within it for example

```
sk = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

i am trying to group the elements of the array in 3's so would return [012, 345, 678]

to achieve this i am using the code below:

```
sk = [i+j+k for i,j,k in zip(sk[::3], sk[1::3], sk[2::3])]
```

however all this returns in a limitless empty arrays, what am i do wrong to get this output ?

edit i should also mention the input will later on contain strings and this is what i need to combine

so later on the input will be

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
```

and need the result to be

```
[abc , def, ghi]
```

Edit 2

the original code worked, the reason for the empty arrays was because it was nested within another function

Comment: I get `[3, 12, 21]` as output from that, is that not what you expect?

Comment: What kind of values do you mean by `0123, 345, 678`?  Do you want those to be strings, or nested lists, or what?

Comment: i am trying to make the values 012, 345, 678 to be strings and added back into an array list in that order if that makes sense

Comment: [int(str(i)+str(j)+str(k)) for i,j,k in zip(sk[::3], sk[1::3], sk[2::3])]   .. that is you need to convert it first to strings, append them and then convert it back to an integer

Answer (score 4):

Your list is a list of numbers.  Your grouping code is correct, but when you do `i+j+k` for each group, it adds the numbers.  If you want to, say, collect the numbers into nested lists instead, you can do:

```
>>> sk = [list(group) for group in zip(sk[::3], sk[1::3], sk[2::3])]
>>> sk
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

If you want to get strings, make strings:

```
>>> sk = [''.join(str(a) for a in group) for group in zip(sk[::3], sk[1::3], sk[2::3])]
>>> sk
['012', '345', '678']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a grouper recipe in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) to do this:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

print [list(x) for x in (grouper(3,sk))]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```